# Can't compare AnyHashable in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have an array of dictionnaries returned by XCDYoutubeKit pod in a swift projet :

```
print(video?.streamURLs ?? "nothing to print")


[AnyHashable(17): https://r7---sn-8vv-cg0l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&pcm2cms=yes&pl=20&mv=m&initcwndbps=2522500&ipbits=0&ms=au&key=yt6&signature=373890DBE71537EB460B6D5E0C6D6B11066DAAC7.6E0898B1C97F6504432B4A2E96511203B86AFF89&mime=video%2F3gpp&ip=212.68.230.6&dur=275.388&id=o-AALDaM6KxpA6-UX-Zfhcy0MYtZSEWxj3HGfu-aPvZR5z&upn=Wolarcf9l8k&mt=1478956785&mn=sn-8vv-cg0l&itag=17&requiressl=yes&expire=1478978548&lmt=1394298238781402&mm=31&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ratebypass=yes, AnyHashable(135): https://r7---sn-8vv-cg0l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pl=20&initcwndbps=2522500&ipbits=0&key=yt6&ip=212.68.230.6&upn=IqqzaXYA2Ag&expire=1478978548&lmt=1458192852355410&mm=31&clen=26845311&source=youtube&pcm2cms=yes&mv=m&mt=1478956785&ms=au&mn=sn-8vv-cg0l&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&dur=275.008&id=o-AALDaM6KxpA6-UX-Zfhcy0MYtZSEWxj3HGfu-aPvZR5z&signature=86328F117AEF617380C2EE4C0327891683F8571A.C57F883610B44498FEBDF556868860687223BDF2&itag=135&requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ratebypass=yes]
```

I'm trying to compare keys but I'm stuck with something that seems really simple... What I've tried :

```
                for item in (video?.streamURLs)! {

                if item.key == AnyHashable(UInt(17)) {
                    //never pass here
                    print(item.key)
                }
            }
```

I'm not familiar with the new AnyHashable type but from what I understood, it should allow the == operator. 
[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyhashable)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks !

Comment: do you receive a compile time error, a runtime error or does the code simply not yield the expected result?

Comment: `Int` conforms to `AnyHashable`, why not simply `[17: https:...` -- `if item.key == 17`? Declare the dictionary as `[Int:String]` or `[Int:URL]`

Comment: @vadian if item.key == 17 gives me a compile error : binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyHashable' and 'Int'

Comment: @luk2302 no error, the condition is just not verified between two obviously equal AnyHashable(17) values

Comment: @nelsballs Could you please tell us what `print(type(of: item.key.base))` outputs? My guess is that the wrapped type is not a `UInt`.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks, you're right... ! The type is NSNumber and not UInt. In Swift 2.3 I was able to directly compare the key from the dictionnary with the enum used in XCDYoutubeKit  (720p, 1080p , etc...) So I was quite confident to deal with UInt... my bad. Thanks again

Comment: if `streamURLs` is a dictionary you have to enumerate it `if (key, value) in video?.streamURLs {. ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in AnyHashable, [acknowledged by Joe Groff, Swift engineer](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/793124202903506944):

> @0xced Looks like the bug is in AnyHashable. If it's possible to type your dictionary to NSDictionary, that might work around

You have to explicitly use a NSNumber to access values in the streamURLs dictionary with Swift 3.

```
struct YouTubeVideoQuality {
    static let hd720 = NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue)
    static let medium360 = NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360.rawValue)
    static let small240 = NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.small240.rawValue)
}

func playVideo(videoIdentifier: String?) {
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(videoIdentifier) { [weak playerViewController] (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: Error?) in
        if let streamURLs = video?.streamURLs, let streamURL = (streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] ?? streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.hd720] ?? streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.medium360] ?? streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.small240]) {
            playerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
        } else {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```